# How to add block to Magento 2 Luma Theme header?

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

How can I add a block to the magento 2 luma header like in this image? I'm using M2.2 and app/design/frontend/magento directory is empty (i see that referenced a lot).

[image]

Comment: Check your vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/

Comment: are you using any custom theme Or default Luma Theme ?

Comment: please accept answer if it's working. So, other developer can use this answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code at after `top.search` referenceContainer:

> app/code/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">topPromo</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**Note:** Need to change block id `topPromo` with your block Id and need some CSS for positioning.

Comment: Welcome @ Will :)

Comment: You can also upvote so question can be consider as close :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your default.xml file at below path

> /app/code/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customFile" template="Magento_Search::customFile.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Now, create your template file at below path

> /app/code/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Search/templates/customFile.phtml

```
<div class="block" style="float: right;margin-bottom: 0.5%;margin-top: 0.5%;">
    <?php echo __('This is Custom Text File'); ?>
</div>
```

Hope, It may be helpful for you.

Comment: Why not just us a CMS Widget to place a CMS static block there. Then no code is needed

Comment: Exactly. You are right. But, it's just a one type of solution I added.

Comment: How do you get a cms static block to show in the header between the logo and the search?

Comment: reference container header-wrapper is used for display in center. I add phtml into this container and add some css.