# Magento 2 - Luma theme header customization

Tags: magento2

Where is located the file of the header of luma theme ?

I want to add some text and facebook icon to header and I can´t find where I do that !

Please Help !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create CMS static block(s) and add these in your theme default.xml file :

**Step 1 :**

in Admin go to

> Content->Elements->Blocks

create CMS block there and add its identifier `header-text-info` and in 
**Package/theme/Magento_Theme/lahyout/default.xml** file add below code after  tag :

**Step 2:**

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <container htmlClass="header-text" htmlTag="div" name="ship.notice.col-12">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header.notice.text" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header-text-info</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

- And after that flush your cache,

  like that you can add header text or whatever info you want i.e facebook icon , phone number etc. This block will show at top of your site.

Comment: it works ! But actually at the top of site and I want by side of the logo. at the top of navigation bar @Naveed Asim

Comment: you can change its location by changing the "after.body.start" to "header.panel" and change before="-" to after="logo"

Comment: worked ! thanks ! @Naveed Asim 
But do u know the name of the panel where search bar is ?

Comment: you will find it, in /vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Header and footer are in the html folder of the theme.

Check "vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml" or "vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml"

Comment: I see php code but how do I add the text here ?

Comment: Do you want it between logo and search box ?

Comment: this could be helpful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237194/how-to-add-block-to-magento-2-luma-theme-header/237213#237213

Comment: @Pawan I already tried but not with success